# Were there prophets, in and out of Israel, who were not recorded in the Tanakh?

Tags: gentiles, nevua-prophecy, navi-prophets, apocrypha

Were there prophets, in and out of Israel, who were not recorded in the Tanakh? Have other sources determined the identities of some of them? Please cite the sources, if any. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/115039/source-for-the-total-number-of-prophets